# Pulling different data into ListBox

Tags: wpf

How I should to do this? I tried the following:

In Xaml:

```
        <DataTemplate x:Key="LogDataTemplate" DataType="data:Type1">
             <TextBlock Text="Type1" />                
        </DataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="LogDataTemplate" DataType="data:Type2">
            <TextBlock Text="Type2" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

     <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding source}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource LogDataTemplate}" />    
 </UserControl>
```

In view model(which is set as DataContext of the UserControl):

```
member x.source = new ObservableCollection<Object>()
```

But have an error about duplicates of DataTemplate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `x:Key` parameter. Implicit DataTemplates is what you want here.

**Edit:** Here is a really small working example :

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;
            Rectangles = new ObservableCollection<object>() { new RedRectangle(), new BlueRectangle() };
        }
        public ObservableCollection<object> Rectangles { get; set; }
    }
    public class RedRectangle { }
    public class BlueRectangle { }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:StackOverflow"
        Width="500" Height="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:RedRectangle}">
            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Red" />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:BlueRectangle}">
            <Rectangle Width="16" Height="16" Fill="Blue" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Rectangles}" />
</Window>
```

Comment: But what I should write  in ItemTemplate now?

Comment: Nothing, the template will be automatically applied based on DataType.

Comment: I see only types of elements in listbox - not data template for this types. Perhaps it because source collection have type ObservableCollection<Object> and Object not casts to data template's type?

Comment: No, this should work. I edited my answer with a very simple working example.

Comment: Please considere marking as answer if it solves your issue ;)

Comment: ok) But may be you know how I can use F# type from namespace like "module CommonNamespace.ModuleLikeCSharpPublicClass". In this way I can get target type only as ModuleLikeCSharpPublicClass.MyTargetType... But how I should write it dotted notation into Xaml?

Comment: I'm not into F#, sorry :/ You can add .NET namespace as xmlns (xml namespace) though, like the "local" one on the code above.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's implicit data templates like @Sisyphe mentions.

But your real problem is, you've named both templates the same thing. `x:Key` is a dictionary key, it needs to be unique within its scope. That's what the error is about.

Having said that, you'll be better off with implicit data templates in this case as @Sisyphe mentions.